Add a hash to the Power BI URL when embedding in an Angular project
I have made several reports in power bi which are public.
But the client does not want the URL of those reports to be accessible from the web page when inspecting the page.
They do not have enough budget to use Azure and use the premium version with RLS.
Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to encrypt said URL for when the embedding is carried out and
it cannot be replicated on another page.
`
<iframe title="Propuesta Maqueta"
 width="100%"

 height="700"

 [src]="power_bi_url"     <-- Is it possible to add a hash?

 frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">

</iframe>


